# How can I count number of grid graph's trees in short time?

Tags: algorithm

Assume a situation where (L + 1)^2 nodes are place in a L x L grid. Nodes are randomly linked with nearest neighbors (so the degree of node is 0,1,2,3 or 4). Of course, the graph isn't generally connected, and say you know the number of connected components of the initial state.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVoID.png) (Fig1: example of initial state)

Now you choose two neighboring nodes, and

- If they are linked, cut the edge.
- If they aren't linked, link them with a new edge.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO1g2.png) (Fig2: example of the operation)

You repeat this cut-or-link operation many times.

Then, every time you execute the operation, how can you know the number of connected components in short time like O(log L^2) or O(L)? It is easy to compute the number in O(L^2) if you maintain an (L + 1)^2-length array whose element indicates the index of the tree it belongs to. Also, you can use UnionFind algorithm but, because it can't delink nodes, frequently you have to reconstruct the forest in O(L^2 * log L^2).

Does anyone have an idea? It seemed Link/Cut Tree algorithm was suitable, but probably it can't be used in this problem (for example, Link/Cut Tree's `cut(v)` function receives only one argument where `v` is an index of node.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity

Comment: Actually https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019667749290004V is better than the general purpose algorithms.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you for your comment. I've once heard of dynamic connectivity but never gone into the details. I'll read the pages you told me from now.